# Quota cost for YouTube Live Streaming API methods

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

As far as I understand correctly, a call to a Youtube API will cost 'units', and I have a daily default of 10000 units, which is reset every day around midnight (Pacific Time).

On https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost, these costs are mentioned for every resource and method. However, I cannot find the Live Streaming resources on that page.

I'm interested particularly in resources 'liveBroadcast' and 'liveStream' and their methods to list, insert, update, and delete them, including 'bind' to bind a liveStream to a liveBroadcast.

Is there a quota-page for the Youtube Live resources and methods?